# Fixing center distance of worm gear

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, manufacturing-engineering, power-transmission

For a worm gear setup in a metal casing, is there a way to fix the center distance between the worm and the worm gear being too far away other than scrapping the casing and make a new one?
[image]

*Reference gearbox*

Comment: I'm guessing a good machinist could hack something up.

Answer (score 0):

You could remake the gears instead.

We'd really need some better information and / or photos to understand fully what you are asking. Did you make the casing yourself?

Comment: I added a picture I found on the internet. The casing I have is similar. Cast then machined. Remaking the gears probably won't help because the worm is already meshing with the back of some casings, so making larger gears to close the gap would cause more meshing.

Comment: It seems as though someone has made an error and you have had a batch of casings made to a faulty design. I think you should confess to this in your question and say how many faulty gearboxes you've got. This may affect the economics of a setup to modify the faulty casings. You'd need to supply a drawing of the casing for anyone to be able to assess your options. If there's enough metal there it may be possible to machine a new bearing support.

Comment: You should _edit your question_ to point out that your photo is representative, not your actual assembly.  Better yet, _show_ your actual assembly.  Depending on the details, it may be possible to machine your casing, or to weld and then remachine your casing -- or not.

Comment: Since the drawings are for internal use only, I can't post them here. We have 200+ casings with this problem. The supplier's solution is to enlarge and move the existing shaft hole closer to the worm gear and then use a bushing to fit the shaft's sleeve bearing. It works, but definitely not a good representation of quality.

Comment: @Thalva I think you're lucky that fix is even on the table. Even simple fixes to simple parts can be very difficult to fix through modification and you're talking about a huge change to a complex part. If you're looking for a tidier, easier fix it doesn't exist.